# Entity Framework Core retrieve single object from table

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

I am trying to retrieve a single row from my table using Entity Framework core. This seems to be very simple, but i cannot get it to work.

I am able to get the list by using

_context.COUNTRY.ToList();

This gives me the full list of countries in my table. Now I need to get only one country that matches the ID. How to do this as Find() is missing in the EF core. Can we do a SELECT with WHERE. Can someone help me with the syntax.

My COUNTRY model is as shown below

public partial class COUNTRY
    {
        public string COUNTRYID { get; set; }
        public string COUNTRYNAME { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 1):

This worked

_context.COUNTRY.Single(c => c.COUNTRYID == id);

Comment: You can also do SingleOrDefault incase you don't want it to break. This answer works fine but i does "select * from table". If you want only fwe columns please do _context.COUNTRY.Where(c => c.COUNTRYID == id).Select(f=>{f.CountryID}).SingleOrDefualt();